# Sending Angular Parameters to external JS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, parameters, external

Sending Parameters from AngularJS To JS File

I have been trying to send information from Angular to an external JS File for days now.
I have tired the ng-model, ng-init, ng-bind and two way directives

```
<body lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-model="baseUrl='http://example.com'" >
<body lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-init=="baseUrl='http://example.com'" >
```

---- javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid','ui.grid.pagination']);
var baseUrl;
```

etc..etc..

Everything I have been seeing from the Angular Directive is to GET data from a java script variable. I need to SET a variable from Angular to a JS File.

The only way I found is to use :

```
    <script>
    var global = {
        baseUrl: 'http://example.com'
    };    
    </script>
```

before i declare

```
<body lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-model="baseUrl='http://example.com'" >
```

in the HTML

This is not an option for me. is there another way around it ? 
Any feedback is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use directives to modify global data - that is the job of a service, or sometimes a controller. But, if you want to ignore this advice, you will need to put your logic in a lifecycle method of the directive. For example, you could add it to the link function. It's a horrible hack, but I already mentioned that.

```
var myModule = angular.module(...);

myModule.directive('directiveName', function factory(injectables) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) { 
       window.myGlobalVariable = 'Living dangerously';
    }
  };
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
});
```

Comment: The problem is to send global config variables ( such as a URL) to the external JavaScript file . Are you saying this is can be done from an angular service ? To be completely honest, I'm starting to convert this external JS into typescript. Not a master of JS, but I'm learning :)

Comment: @deathsonic I am not sure what you are trying to do, to be honest. The tems "send a variable" and "external javascript file" don't really make sense in this context to me. This answer was my best guess as to what you meant.